# How do you gather news articles like Flipboard?

Tags: flipboard

I'm attempting to build an iOS app involving news articles but I am unable to gather full bodies of news articles as well as find news article apis. I've attempted the NYTimes news api but they do not provide the body of an article? How does Flipboard gather full articles from so many different sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Companies partner with flipboard and provide them either with the HTML/CSS or an RSS feed.

https://about.flipboard.com/publishers/partners/